# I spoke to him kindly____ him.

Tags: word-usage, usage

I spoke to him kindly____ him.

A. not to frighten

B. so as not to frighten

C. in order to not frighten

D. for not frightening

The correct answer is B, but I can't figure out why D is not correct. Can

someone help me out?

Comment: C and D are definitely wrong... However, I can't see why A can't be correct? Both A and B are correct. C should be **"In order not to frighten"** and D is incomprehensible.

Comment: @SovereignSun C is acceptable to me, even though I'd prefer the *commonly taught* version. Furthermore, there's a difference between the two versions.

Comment: C is OK, although not the most common way of phrasing it.  A is not correct, because that's not how you indicate purpose in English; it needs a conjoining phrase like "so as not to" or "so that I wouldn't".

Comment: @userr2684291 Maybe is some cases they are acceptable *(a matter of style I guess)* but not in sentences with split infinitives, for instance: **"I went for a walk in order not to do the dishes"** *(**to not do** sounds awfully incorrect)*

Comment: @SovereignSun The rule about split infinitive is nonsense, because you can tell a different thing by splitting infinitive. "They vote immediately to stop.."(*immediately* modifies *vote*); "They vote to immediately stop"(*immediately* modifies *stop*)

Comment: @user178049 I was speaking of **"in order not to"** and **"in order to not"**

Comment: I'm more curious as to why you think D is correct. In the meantime, I agree that B is the "best" answer, though I would also agree that I think C would be OK if we could mark multiple answers as correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I spoke kindly for not frightening him

Reason 1:

It's ambiguous.  This could either mean:

- I spoke kindly in exchange for not frightening him

or

- I spoke kindly so that I would not frighten him

Context can't help too much because of ...

Reason 2:

*For* usually expresses duration if the *X* in *X for Y* is a verb or phrase.  So it's unexpected that you use another meaning of *for* (expressing purpose or intended consequence) here.

Comment: The answer is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: Educate me.  Explain.

Comment: While it's idiomatic to speak *for a reason* or *for an hour*, it's not correct to speak *for frightening* or *for not frightening*. The answer, as the comments above indicate, is *so as not to frighten* although Answer A would serve with a comma after kindly. Answer C is awkward and Answer D is plain wrong.

Comment: "I received this reward for not frightening him." - an example where it is valid - but yeah, the use in my examples is clumsy and awkward at best, but it is how they would be interpreted by a listener (and hopefully not a reader).  OP already knew the right answer but was asking why D was incorrect.

Comment: The phrase *for not frightening* may work after certain verbs but the verb in question is *spoke*, not *received* - and the answer is B.